# Need help finding an indentation/syntax error in my list code

Tags: python, syntax, indentation

Okay, so I'm working through a doctest to check all of my code. I have about five other solutions that work fine - so the meat and potatoes of my code is functional. However, I am failing one test constantly, and getting False instead of True. Below is my code

```
def duplist(lst1, lst2):
    lst1Counter = 0
    lst2Counter = 0
    while lst1Counter in range(len(lst1)) and lst2Counter in range(len(lst2)):
        if lst1[0] == lst2[0]:
            lst1Counter+=1
            lst2Counter+=1
        else:
            lst2Counter+=1

    if lst1Counter not in range(len(lst1)):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The point of the list is to see if the first list is a sublist of the second. It's all set except for one test.

```
duplist([15,1,100],[20,15,30,50,1,100])==True
```

I always return False. It's got to be a small syntax/indentation error - but I can't find it anywhere. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: You're only ever comparing the first elements of the two lists.

Comment: Do you have any advice? It works for all other tests. The logic is it checks the first index of both lists. And if they do not match, you increment 1 to the second list. If they both match, you increment 1 to each and move on. I think it's a really small change that needs to be made

Comment: You increment the counters... and then you compare the **first** elements again.

Comment: "It works for all other tests" means very little. The provided test cases for this kind of thing very frequently suck.

Comment: Well...I mean, do you have any input as to what is wrong here? I don't understand what you mean with your input. I'm a new programmer, so if you could point me in some kind of direction, it'd be nice.

Comment: The thing that is wrong is that you're comparing the first elements of each list over and over: `if lst1[0] == lst2[0]`. You're not doing anything with those counters.

Comment: What do you think those zeros mean?

Comment: The zeroes to me mean they are the first index in list 1 and list 2. I guess I am unsure how to apply the counters and make them coincide

Comment: Well... when `i` is equal to `0`, which elements of each list would you want to compare that time around? When `i` is equal to `1`, which elements that time? Do you see a pattern?

Comment: But also - why did you think the error had to be with syntax or indentation?

Comment: I get that i would make sense....but I just absolutely have no clue how to alter my code for it to make sense. Drawing a blank

Comment: I just got it. I'm a huge idiot. Thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualizing what your code is doing might point you in the right direction.
Let's review the code:

For `duplist([15, 1, 100], [20, 15, 30, 50, 1, 100])`, after the completion of the while loop, you are left with:

```
lst1Counter = 0
lst2Counter = 3  # for 3 iterations where lst1[0] != lst2[0] in the above case
```

Then you are looking whether `lst1Counter not in range(len(lst1))` which is:

```
if 0 not in [0, 1, 2]
```

That is a false statement, since 0 is in [0, 1, 2].
Hence, it returns False instead of True.

Also, let us know if you need some help with your code, it is not actually checking whether a lst1 is a sublist of lst2.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for this - I just got it. One line of code made the difference. if lst1[lst1Counter] == lst2[lst2Counter]: was what I needed. Not sure why that worked, sort of a short in the dark. If you could explain, maybe? It'd be huge

Comment: Sure, but changing this only works if array2 has the elements in the same order as array1 (like you mentioned). Again, try to visualize it: (Still writing give me a sec)

Comment: Let lst1Counter, lst2Counter be abrreviated lC1, IC2 = 0, 0  . --- After 1st iteration, lst1[0] = 15 != 20 = lst2[0], --- so now for 2nd iteration, lC1 = 0, lC2 = 1, hence lst1[0] = 15 == 15 = lst2[1], ----for 3rd iteration lC1 = 1, lC2 = 2, hence here lst1[1] = 1 != 30 = lst2[2], --- and for 4th iteration, lC1 = 1, lC2 = 3, hence here lst[1] = 1 != 50 = lst[3], ---and for 5th iteration, lC1 = 1, lC2 = 4, hence here lst1[1] = 1 == 1 = lst2[4] and so on...

Comment: Also, it's unfortunate the formatting of the code did not end up well. It's because it's much harder to structure it in the comments. Hope this helped! Happy coding!